# Why can't I leave the keyboard on iOS to send the Post in the React Native App?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, button, keyboard

In an App created with [npx react-native init MyApp](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup)

I am having a problem that I cannot correct.

I have a section to upload images and text to a database, Firebase.
On the screen I have a button to send the Post, as I show in the first image.
When I start to type the text and it is abundant, the Send button disappears, and I cannot send the text since I cannot leave the keyboard.
The problem also arises when I add an image, since it occupies more and the send button also disappears, and I cannot leave the keyboard.

I have added ScroolView to the View that contains this screen, but it breaks the application, brings the items to the top of the screen.

On other screens, I remove the lower task bar with a function to have more space for the device's keyboard, but this time I don't know how to solve the problem.
In iOS it is totally impossible to leave the keyboard to access the Send Post Button.
On Android devices, the Button is slightly displayed, as I show in the Android image, and also the screen automatically Scrools as I add text.
However, on iOS this does not happen, and I cannot send the Post.
How can I correct this error?
How can I make the application keyboard disappear when I want it to?

***I EDIT THE QUESTION WITH MORE INFORMATION***

I have tried a solution that the user @MichaelBahl has offered me,
adding KeyboardAvoidingView, and with the text it works, the text scrolls towards the top and always but if we add a large amount of Text and an image, the Send Button disappears at the bottom both in iOS and Android, making it impossible to send of the message.

How to fix this problem on iOS and Android?
I will continue looking for solutions.

I have added a styles file that I forget, these styles with `"styled-components"` are what create the screen

Adding  seems to work, but when I open that screen the buttons are very close to the top, and I can't display the "add image" buttons

***I edit the question again***

I have used `<KeyboardAwareScrollView>` as suggested by user @MuhammadNuman.
This seems to work, but when starting on this screen, the buttons are at the top and thus prevent you from using the buttons on the right side to add images.
All this can happen due to the styles used in my TextInput, but I don't know how to correct it.
I show a new screenshot and a video with the operation of the buttons

[image]
[image]

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react"
import {
  View,
  Text,
  Button,
  Alert,
  ActivityIndicator,
  ScrollView,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  Keyboard,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
} from "react-native"

import ActionButton from "react-native-action-button"
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'
import FontAwesome5 from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5'
import ImagePicker from "react-native-image-crop-picker"

import storage from '@react-native-firebase/storage'
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore'

import globalStyles from "../styles/global"
import {
  InputField,
  InputWrapper,
  AddImage,
  SubmitBtn,
  SubmitBtnText,
  StatusWrapper
} from '../styles/AddPostStyles'
import { AuthContext } from "../navigation/AuthProvider"

const AddPostScreen = () => {
  const { user, logout } = useContext(AuthContext)

  const [image, setImage] = useState(null)
  const [uploading, setUploading] = useState(false)
  const [transferred, setTransferred] = useState(0)
  const [post, setPost] = useState(null)

  const takePhotoFromCamera = () => {
    ImagePicker.openCamera({
      width: 1200,
      height: 780,
      cropping: true,
    }).then((image) => {
      console.log(image)
      const imageUri = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? image.sourceURL : image.path
      setImage(imageUri)
    })
  }

  const choosePhotoFromLibrary = () => {
    ImagePicker.openPicker({
      width: 1200,
      height: 780,
      cropping: true,
    }).then((image) => {
      console.log(image)
      const imageUri = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? image.sourceURL : image.path
      setImage(imageUri)
    })
  }

  const submitPost = async () => {
    const imageUrl = await uploadImage()
    console.log('Image Url', imageUrl)

    firestore()
      .collection('posts')
      .add({
        userId: user.uid,
        post: post,
        postImg: imageUrl,
        postTime: firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date()),
        likes: null,
        comments: null
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Post Added...')
        Alert.alert(
          'Post published!',
          'Your post has been published Successfully!',
        )
        setPost(null)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Something went wrong with added post to firestore.', error)
      })
  }

  const uploadImage = async () => {

    if (image == null) {
      return null
    }
    const uploadUri = image
    let filename = uploadUri.substring(uploadUri.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)

    // Add timestad to File Name
    const extension = filename.split('.').pop()
    const name = filename.split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.')
    filename = name + Date.now() + '.' + extension

    setUploading(true)
    setTransferred(0)

    const storageRef = storage().ref(`photos/${filename}`)

    const task = storageRef.putFile(uploadUri)
    // Set transferred state
    task.on('state_changed', (taskSnapshot) => {
      console.log(`${taskSnapshot.bytesTransferred} transferred out of ${taskSnapshot.totalBytes}`)

      setTransferred(
        Math.round(taskSnapshot.bytesTransferred / taskSnapshot.totalBytes) * 100
      )
    })

    try {
      await task

      const url = await storageRef.getDownloadURL()
      setUploading(false)
      setImage(null)
      /*  Alert.alert(
         'Imagen subida!',
         'Tu imagen se subio correctamente!',
       ) */
      return url

    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
      return null
    }

  }

  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView
    behavior={Platform.OS === "android" ? "padding" : "height"}
      style={{ flex: 1 }}>

      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
        <View style={globalStyles.container}>

          <InputWrapper>
            {image != null ? <AddImage source={{ uri: image }} /> : null}
            <InputField
              placeholder="¿Qué tienes en mente?"
              multiline
              numberOfLines={4}
              value={post}
              onChangeText={(content) => setPost(content)}
            />
            {uploading ? (
              <StatusWrapper>
                <Text>{transferred} % Completed!</Text>
                <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#27AE60" />
              </StatusWrapper>
            ) : (
              <SubmitBtn onPress={submitPost}>
                <SubmitBtnText>Post</SubmitBtnText>
              </SubmitBtn>
            )}
          </InputWrapper>

          <ActionButton buttonColor="rgb(26, 188, 156)">
            <ActionButton.Item
              buttonColor='#9b59b6'
              title="New Task" onPress={() => console.log("notes tapped!")}>
              <Icon name="md-create" style={globalStyles.actionButtonIcon} />
            </ActionButton.Item>
            <ActionButton.Item
              buttonColor='#3498db'
              title="Take Photp"
              onPress={takePhotoFromCamera}>
              <Icon name="camera-outline" style={globalStyles.actionButtonIcon} />
            </ActionButton.Item>
            <ActionButton.Item
              buttonColor='#1abc9c'
              title="Elegir"
              onPress={choosePhotoFromLibrary}>
              <Icon name="md-images-outline" style={globalStyles.actionButtonIcon} />
            </ActionButton.Item>
          </ActionButton>

        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  )
}

export default AddPostScreen
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  }})

export default KeyboardAvoidingComponent
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

CODE:

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react"
import { View, Text, Button, Alert, ActivityIndicator, ScrollView } from "react-native"

import ActionButton from "react-native-action-button"
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'
import FontAwesome5 from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5'
import ImagePicker from "react-native-image-crop-picker"

import storage from '@react-native-firebase/storage'
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore'

import globalStyles from "../styles/global"
import {
  InputField,
  InputWrapper,
  AddImage,
  SubmitBtn,
  SubmitBtnText,
  StatusWrapper
} from '../styles/AddPostStyles'
import { AuthContext } from "../navigation/AuthProvider"

const AddPostScreen = () => {
  const { user, logout } = useContext(AuthContext)

  const [image, setImage] = useState(null)
  const [uploading, setUploading] = useState(false)
  const [transferred, setTransferred] = useState(0)
  const [post, setPost] = useState(null)

  const takePhotoFromCamera = () => {
    ImagePicker.openCamera({
      width: 1200,
      height: 780,
      cropping: true,
    }).then((image) => {
      console.log(image)
      const imageUri = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? image.sourceURL : image.path
      setImage(imageUri)
    })
  }

  const choosePhotoFromLibrary = () => {
    ImagePicker.openPicker({
      width: 1200,
      height: 780,
      cropping: true,
    }).then((image) => {
      console.log(image)
      const imageUri = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? image.sourceURL : image.path
      setImage(imageUri)
    })
  }

  const submitPost = async () => {
    const imageUrl = await uploadImage()
    console.log('Image Url', imageUrl)

    firestore()
      .collection('posts')
      .add({
        userId: user.uid,
        post: post,
        postImg: imageUrl,
        postTime: firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date()),
        likes: null,
        comments: null
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Post Added...')
        Alert.alert(
          'Post published!',
          'Your post has been published Successfully!',
        )
        setPost(null)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Something went wrong with added post to firestore.', error)
      })
  }

  const uploadImage = async () => {

    if (image == null) {
      return null
    }
    const uploadUri = image
    let filename = uploadUri.substring(uploadUri.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)

    // Add timestad to File Name
    const extension = filename.split('.').pop()
    const name = filename.split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.')
    filename = name + Date.now() + '.' + extension

    setUploading(true)
    setTransferred(0)

    const storageRef = storage().ref(`photos/${filename}`)

    const task = storageRef.putFile(uploadUri)
    // Set transferred state
    task.on('state_changed', (taskSnapshot) => {
      console.log(`${taskSnapshot.bytesTransferred} transferred out of ${taskSnapshot.totalBytes}`)

      setTransferred(
        Math.round(taskSnapshot.bytesTransferred / taskSnapshot.totalBytes) * 100
      )
    })

    try {
      await task

      const url = await storageRef.getDownloadURL()
      setUploading(false)
      setImage(null)
      /*  Alert.alert(
         'Imagen subida!',
         'Tu imagen se subio correctamente!',
       ) */
      return url

    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
      return null
    }

  }

  return (
    <View style={globalStyles.container}>

      <InputWrapper>
          {image != null ? <AddImage source={{ uri: image }} /> : null}
          <InputField
            placeholder="¿Qué tienes en mente?"
            multiline
            numberOfLines={4}
            value={post}
            onChangeText={(content) => setPost(content)}
          />
          {uploading ? (
            <StatusWrapper>
              <Text>{transferred} % Completed!</Text>
              <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#27AE60" />
            </StatusWrapper>
          ) : (
            <SubmitBtn onPress={submitPost}>
              <SubmitBtnText>Post</SubmitBtnText>
            </SubmitBtn>
          )}    
      </InputWrapper>

      <ActionButton buttonColor="rgb(26, 188, 156)">
        <ActionButton.Item
          buttonColor='#9b59b6'
          title="New Task" onPress={() => console.log("notes tapped!")}>
          <Icon name="md-create" style={globalStyles.actionButtonIcon} />
        </ActionButton.Item>
        <ActionButton.Item
          buttonColor='#3498db'
          title="Take Photp"
          onPress={takePhotoFromCamera}>
          <Icon name="camera-outline" style={globalStyles.actionButtonIcon} />
        </ActionButton.Item>
        <ActionButton.Item
          buttonColor='#1abc9c'
          title="Elegir"
          onPress={choosePhotoFromLibrary}>
          <Icon name="md-images-outline" style={globalStyles.actionButtonIcon} />
        </ActionButton.Item>
      </ActionButton>

    </View>


  )
}

export default AddPostScreen
```

//////////////////////////

```
import styled from 'styled-components'
    
    export const InputWrapper = styled.View`
        flex: 1;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #2e64e515;
    `
    
    export const InputField = styled.TextInput`
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        font-size: 24px;
        text-align: center;
        width:90%;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    `
    
    export const AddImage = styled.Image`
        width: 100%;
        height: 250px;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    `
    
    export const StatusWrapper = styled.View`
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    `
    
    export const SubmitBtn = styled.TouchableOpacity`
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: center;
        background-color: #2e64e515;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 10px 25px;
    `
    
    export const SubmitBtnText = styled.Text`
        font-size: 18px;
        font-family: 'Lato-Bold';
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #2e64e5;
    `
```

Comment: Checkout https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboardavoidingview#example

Comment: Great this seemed to work, when I added the code it worked but then it stopped.
  When I add an image and very long text, the button disappears and there is no way to send the Post.
I will edit the question since in Android when adding a large amount of text and an image, the same thing happens. And in this way I will show your idea

Answer (score 2):

you should use [react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view)

```
yarn add react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view
```

it will resolve your issue.

## Usage

```js
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view'


<KeyboardAwareScrollView>
  <View>
    <TextInput />
  </View>
</KeyboardAwareScrollView>
```

**Note: if you are using react-native<65 then you should use `react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view@0.9.4`**

Comment: Thank you @MuhammadNuman , if I am with `0.66.1`. And for Android what do I use? You see that I also have the problem on Android

Comment: @MiguelEspeso can you try `react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view@0.9.4` package and let me know if it is working as expected on your side or not.

Comment: I'm sorry to say this didn't work out for me. The elements of the page are raised to the top of the screen and it prevents me from adding photos. See a screenshot I have uploaded to https://imgbb.com/: https://i.ibb.co/LdjtCp9/Archivo-000.png
I have gone through the documentation and I think I am doing fine

Comment: @MiguelEspeso can you add a reproducible example from git so I can check on my side?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/841194e10a253f7ddcc76974415f9173.git

Comment: @MiguelEspeso this is just a code file, I wanna a whole container app with file imported packages and react-native version

Comment: The application has 29 files, I leave you a sample of what is happening when adding your code: https://files.fm/u/87apbvu2e#/view/akuwmx36v

Comment: @MiguelEspeso but from the above gist. i have to make RN project and spent more time on reproduce issue instead of fix

Comment: Check the code, I have added the closest files, the files I think are appropriate. It is a problem of styles, but I understand what is happening

Comment: I have tried your @MuhammadNuman code again and it works, but the problem is the startup, which shows the very top on the screen, could you somehow correct this?

Comment: @MiguelEspeso which startup issue? which shoes the very top of the screen? can you attach a screenshot here?

Comment: @MiguelEspeso any update?

Comment: I have not achieved anything new. I only need the elements to be shown below on the screen, as you can see in the video and in the screenshot, I cannot act with the buttons that the App has to add images to the "Post". Do you suggest any ideas?

Comment: @MiguelEspeso you can add a button outside of the safe area view

Comment: I don't know what else I can do, I've tried so many things. This is very rare. I don't know what is the problem in the application that is causing this

Comment: @MiguelEspeso can you show me on google meet. may be i can help you

Comment: I don't have Google Meet installed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239265/discussion-between-muhammad-numan-and-miguel-espeso).

Comment: I must say that I don't know how to speak English

Comment: Note, publishing contact info here can get you into at least two kinds of trouble. I recommend against it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I found you a solution. Follow the previous steps I mentioned which  are:

1. `yarn add react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view`
2. `import { useRef } from 'react';`
3. `import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view';`
4. `const scrollViewRef = useRef();`
5. Use the `KeyboardAwareScrollView` and set its ref you just declared.

   ```
    <KeyboardAwareScrollView ref={scrollViewRef} >
        <View style={{flex: 1}} >
            //Content
        </View>
    </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
   ```
6. With your `TextInput` (`InputField` in your case), make sure to scroll to the end every time the text is changed.

   ```
    <TextInput
        onChangeText={text => {
            setText(text);
            scrollViewRef.current.scrollToEnd({animated:true});
        }
    />
   ```
7. That should work. If not here's a snack project I created that shows it working https://snack.expo.dev/@bgcodes/7ff849

Comment: I appreciate the effort you are making to help me. I've tried your new option, and it doesn't work. I even have an error with useRef, despite calling it in React, it gives an error and breaks the App.
I've seen his example, but I don't know why it doesn't work for me. I don't know what to do anymore, this is a bit frustrating, but I have to keep looking for a solution.
Should you delete any of the questions, sad that they give you the reward if your answers don't work.

Comment: I don't know why they took away 2 reputation points from me for trying to help.
But anyways if the snack example I gave you is working but it is not working on your project then there must be something in your project that is causing issues which we won't be able to tell without actually looking at your code. Sorry, I can't be any help.